# How to disable cancel button on the Job progress bar dialog?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, jobs

How to disable cancel button on the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job` progress bar dialog?

I mean a window that is displayed when you set `setUser(true)`.

Comment: Your Job's that important? Why show it to the user if you don't want them to be able to cancel it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The progress dialog which is shown (`org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressMonitorFocusJobDialog`) does not support disabling the cancel button from the Job.

If you want to be sure a Job runs to completion make it a system job (`setSystem(true)`) which also means the progress dialog is not shown.